# Role of sonarqube and sonarqube scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Based on what I know sonar.properties need to be created in your java project and then execute the sonar scanner to scan the project for issues.

I am not sure if it is Sonar scanner who finds the issues or is it sonarqube?

Is it possible to use sonarqube scanner only to find the issues?

Please help.

Comment: Please include your desired results and what you have tried so far in your question. You have read the docs right? http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set the [analysis parameters](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) to either `publish`, which will send the reports to SonarQube or `preview`, which will not.

Specifically you need this in your properties file:

```
sonar.analysis.mode=preview
```